# Pyspark. How to extract a datetime value from single row dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've got a spark dataframe, and trying to get a value for next using.

```
max_dttm = spark.sql("""select max(issue_dttm) from psycho_sb.yso_sendsay_im_issues""")
```

It looks like that:

```
+-------------------+
|    max(issue_dttm)|
+-------------------+
|2018-12-25 09:01:30|
+-------------------+
```

How i can extract that value in timestamp/datetime format?
I want to assign it to a variable.

Comment: `max_dttm.collect()`maybe ?

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work, i'm already trying, the result is: Row(max(issue_dttm)=datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 25, 9, 1, 30))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this :

```
max_dttm = spark.sql("""select max(issue_dttm) as max_issue_dttm from psycho_sb.yso_sendsay_im_issues""")
max_issue_dttm = max_dttm.collect()[0].max_issue_dttm
```

Comment: It works, if i Print the result:                                                
`print(max_issue_dttm)`                                                                                                
 `2018-12-25 09:01:30`                                                                                                    But i dont't understand, how i can assign this value to a variable in the next step?

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand. max_issue_dttm is a variable